# Multilanguage page with all indexes pages in folders and 302 redirect from main index

Tags: html, .htaccess, redirect, cookies, web

I have a multilanguage website:
https://www.bestofcinqueterre.com/

when it is requested index page checks the browser language for new users or cookies for returned users and redirect them, for example:
Header ("Location: /en/");

I found this:

> Problems found: You use a 302 redirect. This means, that the actually
>   content is temporary not reachable and will come back soon. To use a
>   302 redirection for generally moved pages is a bad idea.

So I don't know what to do, I checked a lot of websites and I found some like mine and a lot which has english index in the root and all other files in the folders.

Should I move /en/index to /index? If yes is there an easy htaccess rule to do that leaving the file in the folder?

Or should I improve the redirect in some way?

Comment: Be careful, a "/this/is/a/folder" assumption about a URL may be misleading.  It's possible that "is", for example, in the URL is actually a GET var.

As far as the error goes, have you tried a 301?

Comment: @Kevin_Kinsey there is no error at the moment, I've noticed that some websites mark this as a problem, so I am not sure if I am doing that correctly... at the moment site.com has no page, this page has redirect to DIFFERENT pages for each user: en/ it/ fr/ etc

Comment: Right; do they complain if you send 301 instead of a 302?  <?php header("Location: /fr",true,"301");

Comment: where did you get the highlighted "Problems found" statement?  is that from a search engine optimization program? i want to understand your goals here.

Comment: @Kevin_Kinsey with permanent redirection it doesn't show warning. But I am not sure that it is correct thing... Index pages redirects to different pages each time...

Comment: True; probably what we're seeing is an actual lack of complete understanding in the SEO checker ;-)

Comment: @WEBjuju I want do everything as it should, it was not easy to decide how to create first page for multilangage website... I used some web page performance that gave me such result-error. And I am asking, what is the correct way for the structure of such website...

Comment: well, you may want to google 302 and seo as keywords and then restate your question.  for my purposes your site looks great in google (https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Abestofcinqueterre.com&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) so, i wouldn't risk messing it up by changing the redirect.  you just might really mess things up.  performance wise, you're fine with the 302.  semantically, the 301 is wrong - but that's my opinion and the 301 302 battle is probably no where near complete, so i respect whatever works.  302 is working for you, according to your google results.

Comment: @WEBjuju thank you for your help so I'll continue this way (302). Google at the moment puts english index in the root, even if there is canonical /en/ url, well, it works yes, I just want to do things correctly :) thank you!

Comment: i'll add it as a solution if you'll toss me points for solving it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could go with a splash page like [UPS.com](https://www.ups.com/), and then redirect with javascript (based on a php-built trigger if you need to use the server side detection).

That would avoid your 302 and leave search engine fodder for bots to follow (because you would have the links on that splash page).

**Edit after checking your site**

[image]

You are currently sending a 301 right now, which will be wrong for search engines since they will expect that your site has permanently moved to /en/ which is not true...you just want to redirect them based on language, which imho is a valid reason to issue a 302.

**edit**

you may want to google 302 and seo as keywords and then restate your question. for my purposes your site looks great in google (google.com/…) so, i wouldn't risk messing it up by changing the redirect. you just might really mess things up. performance wise, you're fine with the 302. semantically, the 301 is wrong - but that's my opinion and the 301 302 battle is probably no where near complete, so i respect whatever works. 302 is working for you, according to your google results

Comment: It's not good for travel website, if user comes to my website he doesn't know if it's good or no, so it's bad idea to add one more page... He can quit

Comment: the page you are adding is to prevent the 302...your users won't see that page because by the time it loads, you have detected their language and "clicked" the proper link for them.

Comment: I would imagine the 301 is just to test an answer for my question above.  I also dunno what the problem is with the 302 (assuming as you, it's some SEO tool).  I would imagine, Zhenya, that this idea has merit.  UPS is serious about their tech ;-)

Comment: thx @kevin_kinsey, i wondered if he were testing it.  ups would work better if on that page it realized i was en and redirected me, but they can't do that since they probably have multiople "en" sites for different regions.  zhenya has a great option here since if the browser says en, "click" and they probably never see the splash page at all, while having the chance to feed all his languages to the search engines.

Comment: @WEBjuju Thank you, yes, I am very perfectionist. I have created everything from 0, and add a lot of scripts, like if you try to load: /it/florence it will redirect you to /it/firenze automatically. Well a lot of things, but I not sure if I am right with index page in /en/ folder :)

Comment: @jay-blanchard thanks for the heads up on protocol for the comment-to-answer

Comment: You bet @WEBjuju. Glad to help.